# Pycharm - unable to add pipenv as project interpreter

Tags: pycharm, pipenv

Adding pipenv in project interpreter throws an error.
Please help setting up pipenv on pycharm:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2018.5.18/libexec/bin/pipenv", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pipenv==2018.5.18', 'console_scripts', 'pipenv')()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2018.5.18/libexec/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 722, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2018.5.18/libexec/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 676, in main
    _verify_python3_env()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2018.5.18/libexec/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/_unicodefun.py", line 118, in _verify_python3_env
    'for mitigation steps.' + extra)
RuntimeError: Click will abort further execution because Python 3 was configured to use ASCII as encoding for the environment.  Consult http://click.pocoo.org/python3/for mitigation steps.

This system lists a couple of UTF-8 supporting locales that
you can pick from.  The following suitable locales where
discovered: af_ZA.UTF-8, am_ET.UTF-8, be_BY.UTF-8, bg_BG.UTF-8, ca_ES.UTF-8, cs_CZ.UTF-8, da_DK.UTF-8, de_AT.UTF-8, de_CH.UTF-8, de_DE.UTF-8, el_GR.UTF-8, en_AU.UTF-8, en_CA.UTF-8, en_GB.UTF-8, en_IE.UTF-8, en_NZ.UTF-8, en_US.UTF-8, es_ES.UTF-8, et_EE.UTF-8, eu_ES.UTF-8, fi_FI.UTF-8, fr_BE.UTF-8, fr_CA.UTF-8, fr_CH.UTF-8, fr_FR.UTF-8, he_IL.UTF-8, hr_HR.UTF-8, hu_HU.UTF-8, hy_AM.UTF-8, is_IS.UTF-8, it_CH.UTF-8, it_IT.UTF-8, ja_JP.UTF-8, kk_KZ.UTF-8, ko_KR.UTF-8, lt_LT.UTF-8, nl_BE.UTF-8, nl_NL.UTF-8, no_NO.UTF-8, pl_PL.UTF-8, pt_BR.UTF-8, pt_PT.UTF-8, ro_RO.UTF-8, ru_RU.UTF-8, sk_SK.UTF-8, sl_SI.UTF-8, sr_YU.UTF-8, sv_SE.UTF-8, tr_TR.UTF-8, uk_UA.UTF-8, zh_CN.UTF-8, zh_HK.UTF-8, zh_TW.UTF-8
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you consulted the [link](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/python3/#python-3-surrogate-handling)?

Comment: First, visit the URL that is given in the error. Second, select from one of the locales listed.

Comment: I tried that:
'export LC_ALL=en_GB.UTF-8' and 'export LANG=en_GB.UTF-8'

I did this inside pycharm terminal, still same error. 
en_GB.UTF-8 was taken from the values returned from locale -a, as suggested by the guide.

Comment: But why is this happening in the pycharm in the first place, not elsewhere?

Comment: File encodings in pycharm settings - Project setting is set at System Deault : UTF-8 and Global encoding UTF-8, so why is it trying to use ASCII?

Comment: Relevant ticket in PyCharms' bug tracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-30780

Answer (score 2):

My solution was to add the following to the `~/.profile` file.

```
export LC_ALL=es_ES.UTF-8
export LANG=es_ES.UTF-8
```

**Note** that you should add it to the file I mentioned, and *NOT* to `.bashrc` or `.zshrc`, as the IDE most probably does not read those.

Answer (score 1):

Launching Pycharm from the terminal after setting the env vars worked for me, like this:

`export LC_ALL=es_ES.UTF-8 && export LANG=es_ES.UTF-8 && open -a PyCharm`

You can launch normally after it's already set up once.

Comment: This is a poor aproach

Comment: @JuliusŠ.you are right but it was the only way I managed to, however since the latest version the issue seems to go away

Comment: I finally found out that you should add the env variables to `~/.profile`, which solves the issue too.